# iphone sdk: Posting Video to Facebook throws format not supported error

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I am trying to post videos to my Facebook wall through app but it always gives error "`Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.`"

I have got permissions for `upload_video` and `pubish_actions` too. I don't know what is going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData,@"source",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"", @"name",
                                   description, @"description",
                                   nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                                  [self presentAlertForError:error];
                              }
                              else {
                                  [self showAlert:@"Posted on your wall" title:nil];
                              }
                          }];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the params should be

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                                   @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                       nil];
```

what video format do you have?

according to https://www.facebook.com/help/218673814818907/
the list of supported video types is:

> ```
> 3g2 (Mobile Video)
> 3gp (Mobile Video)
> 3gpp (Mobile Video)
> asf (Windows Media Video)
> avi (AVI Video)
> dat (MPEG Video)
> divx (DIVX Video)
> dv (DV Video)
> f4v (Flash Video)
> flv (Flash Video)
> m2ts (M2TS Video)
> m4v (MPEG-4 Video)
> mkv (Matroska Format)
> mod (MOD Video)
> mov (QuickTime Movie)
> mp4 (MPEG-4 Video)
> mpe (MPEG Video)
> mpeg (MPEG Video)
> mpeg4 (MPEG-4 Video)
> mpg (MPEG Video)
> mts (AVCHD Video)
> nsv (Nullsoft Video)
> ogm (Ogg Media Format)
> ogv (Ogg Video Format)
> qt (QuickTime Movie)
> tod (TOD Video)
> ts (MPEG Transport Stream)
> vob (DVD Video)
> wmv (Windows Media Video)
> ```

look at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/ for more information

Comment: Thanks Babar. I posted the issue on Facebook dev forum. By using same params, the issue is resolved.